# How to write a text across multiple columns in itextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm relatively new to iText 5 .NET (formerly known as iTextSharp). Is there a way to write a text across multiple columns? I can't use colspan as each column has a different color.

```cs
var cell = new PdfPCell() { Padding = 0, BorderWidth = 0, FixedHeight = _slotParam.SlotHeight };
var tgrid = new PdfPTable(3);
tgrid.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { Padding = 0, BackgroundColor = Color.ORANGE, BorderWidth = 0, FixedHeight = _slotParam.SlotHeight });
tgrid.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { Padding = 0, BackgroundColor = Color.WHITE, BorderWidth = 0, FixedHeight = _slotParam.SlotHeight });
tgrid.AddCell(new PdfPCell() { Padding = 0, BackgroundColor = Color.GREEN, BorderWidth = 0, FixedHeight = _slotParam.SlotHeight });

cell.AddElement(tgrid);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(phrase);
paragraph.Leading = 11f;
cell.AddElement(phrase);
mainGrid.AddCell(cell);
```

This is the output that I have, I want to write a text across that 3 colors.

[image]

Comment: You could use a table and set the table cells' border to NO_BORDER

Comment: Done the same but didn't work `var cell = new PdfPCell() { Padding = 0, BorderWidth = 0, FixedHeight = _slotParam.SlotHeight };
                            var tgrid = new PdfPTable(3);
                            tgrid.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;`

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXN4A.png The output I got, I want to write a text across these 3 colors.

Comment: If you have distinct cells, you have to split the text and at it to the individual cells. If you want to span a cell over the three columns for text, you only have one cell and cannot apply the colors as you do. Depending on your exact task I'd propose either having one cell in a table with the whole text and draw the three colors in a cell event; or not using tables at all and draw the colors on the `UnderContent`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution is simple.
By giving NoWrap = true for the first cell will make the text to over lap other cells.
`tgrid.AddCell(new PdfPCell(phrase) { Padding = 0, BackgroundColor = Color.ORANGE, BorderWidth = 0, FixedHeight = _slotParam.SlotHeight, NoWrap = true });` 
[Output] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qaIT.png)
Thank you all for helping.
Cheers.

Comment: If development of the product wouldn't have stopped, such a work-around probably would not work for long. In case of iText 5, though, this should continue working.